# upload to google cloud storage using libcloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, libcloud

I wish to to upload files to google cloud storage. I created a service account, converted the p12 file to a pem file, then referenced the service account email address and pem file in my driver:

```
from libcloud.storage.types import Provider
from libcloud.storage.providers import get_driver


CloudStorage = get_driver(Provider.GOOGLE_STORAGE)
driver = CloudStorage(
    '...@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/my.pem'),
    project='my_project',
)
```

however, when I do

```
driver.list_containers()
```

I get

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidSecurity</Code><Message>The provided security credentials are not valid.</Message><Details>Incorrect Authorization header</Details></Error>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apache-libcloud` uses the S3 protocol for Google Storage.

This means you will need to enable *Interoperability* for Google Storage on the developer console.

Instructions for doing this and generating the keys are available [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys)